# How to delegate exception in aspect

Tags: java, exception, aspect

I have external jar library where I created aspect to handle some situation:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("execution(..")
    private Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Exception ex = null;

        while (zkusDalsiSpojeni) {
            try {
                return pjp.proceed();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               solveException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

yes I can throw some exception here. But I want also make option to throw a custom exception in main project where will be this jar as dependency. What is the best way how to do it ? (Abstract aspect or some delegator ?)

Comment: Do you want to throw exception of unknown type in `process` body? How about to create annotation with class member and check if  the  method, aspect is applied to, is annotated with it, and so you can create instance of this exception type and throw it.

Comment: I want to throw some custom exception but also want to have option to throw some other custom exception which is defined in main project

Answer (score 0):

If you use your aspects with interfaces, you can define annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.Method)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.Runtime)
@interface DesiredException {
   Class<? extends Throwable> value();
}
```

and apply to to required method

```
@DesiredException(IllegalStateException.klass)
```

In your aspect you can check if this annotation is declared, and act accordingly

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature();
DesiredException desiredException = methodSignature.getMethod().getAnnotation(DesiredException.class);
if(desiredException!=null){
    Throwable exception = desiredException.value().newInstance();
    throw exception; 
}
```